# Xcode 13.2 - How to hide git changes in the code editor?

Tags: xcode, xcode13

In the latest release of Xcode 13.2, there has been a new feature, which allows us to see both old new versions of a line. In my opinion, it's kind of difficult to navigate with this feature enabled. Does anyone know how to turn it off?

Comment: "kind of" is an understatement. I find it very difficult to navigate and edit with this enabled.

Answer (score 34):

[image: Icon in the top right with two arrows pointing in opposite directions]

Try these arrow press, it will hide the past code.

Comment: Thank you! Such a relief to disable that.

Answer (score 13):

Found it! There is an arrows icon at the top of the editor, which toggles this "code review" mode

Answer (score 4):

or you can use this shortcut "Show Code Review" or "Hide Code Review"

shift + opt + cmd + return

[image]